# Horizontal Labeled Hierarchy SmartArt in Word 2007 too tall

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, layout

I have a Horizontal Labeled Hierarchy SmartArt object in my Word 2007 document and for some reason the background labels are just too tall.

[image: The background labels are too tall!]

How I can I make it look more like this?

[image: The background labels are just right!]

Trying to size the object doesn't help!

My hierarchy is:

```
A
    B
        C
            D
        E
            F
        G
            H
        I
            J
    K
        L
            M
        N
            O
    P
        Q
            R
        S
            T
        U
    V
        W
            X
    Y
    Z
Label
Label
Label
Label
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select Labels in the layout pane and then Reset Graphic you should be able to shrink all the background columns together, with left-click and drag. Then do much the same with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on to reposition the columns.

This is an alternative to "Trying to size the object" that I found even more fiddly, but I believe ought to work (ie select all `• Label` from Type your text here, **Format, Smaller**). This shrinks height *and* width, which then is difficult to widen again while keeping each column under the right part of the hierarchy. If taking this approach it might be easier to start with *Larger* (to make it easier to move them apart and widen them) before making them Smaller but this involves too much hit and miss for my liking.